# boost property tree, iterators to an element for inserting?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I've searched a lot through the boost manual, and the internet, as I believe it is quite a standard feature?

Well I'm looking into "merging" property trees. - I noticed the function `insert`, and I hope I can merge trees with this?
Below is the line which I am trying to get working:

```
base.insert(base.get_child("BRANCH"), t);
```

`base` and `t` are "property trees", `base` has as (one of many) branch "BRANCH". Now I wish to insert `t` into this branch?
More specifically: how can I get an iterator to "element" if I know that element by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an iterator to an element using the *begin()* method:

```
  base.get_child("BRANCH").begin();
```

In order to insert every element in t on that position, you should use:

```
base.insert(base.get_child("BRANCH").begin(), t.begin(), t.end());
```

If t contains one parent node or you only want to insert the first node, you can use:

```
base.insert(base.get_child("BRANCH").begin(), t.front());
```