# Inserting one boost property tree into another

Tags: c++, insert, copy, boost-propertytree, subtree

I want to copy a subtree from one `ptree` to another. 
i.e. 
src:

```
<abc>
<question>
--some-subtree--
</question>
</abc>
```

and generate:

```
<def>
<Version>1</Version>
<QueueQuestion>
--same-subtree-as-above--
</QueueQuestion>
</def>
```

do something like:

```
ptree genReply(const ptree &pt)
{
ptree ret;
ret.put("def","");
ptree &subtree=ret.find("def")->second;
subtree.put("Version",1);
...
...
...
const Xml::ptree &q=pt.find("abc.Question")->second;
subtree.put_child("QueueQuestion",q);
...
...
return ret;
}
```

However, I get a segmentation fault on `subtree.put_child("QueueQuestion",q);`

Any idea anyone?

Comment: What Mats wants to indicate: there is some code missing in the example, that might be needed to solve the problem. unrelated: welcome to stack overflow. :)

Comment: i seems that pt.find("tag")->second causes trouble and should be replaced with pt.get_child("tag")
also x.put_child should be replced with adding the child and doing y=x.get_child("tag");y.insert(y.begin)(,q.begin(),q.end())
see also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590370/boost-property-tree-iterators-to-an-element-for-inserting)